# ¿Cuál es el método más seguro para encriptar y verificar contraseñas en un login actualmente?

Tags: php, mysql, seguridad, encriptación

Necesito implementar un sistema de login y de gestión de contenido web de administrador del sitio para un TFG.

Mis profesores me han pasado una documentación, en donde utilizan el hash **md5** para ello, pero como viene siendo habitual, he seguido investigando más por la web, porque muchas de las cosas que he estado aprendiendo están obsoletas, sobre todo en PHP, y efectivamente **se desaconseja el uso de md5, sha1 y sha256**.

Por consiguiente, he encontrado una biblioteca o una extensión nativa de PHP llamada **password hashing** o encriptación de contraseñas dicho en castellano, pero he visto documentación acerca de esto que data del año 2015-2016 incluso, con lo que me ha hecho dudar bastante acerca de la seguridad de usar esta extensión.

Los principales métodos de esta extensión son:

- password_algos
- password_hash
- password_needs_rehash
- password_verify
- password_get_info

Me fastidia y me preocupa que mi forma de aprender sea en base a malas prácticas o cosas obsoletas, así que, es por ello que acudo a esta plataforma para preguntaros qué método es el más recomendado para hacer esta labor de grabar los datos en la base de datos de MySQL, consultar en la base de datos si el usuario y contraseña son correctos y loguear en caso de que sea correcto... ¿Se sigue utilizando el método que he descrito más arriba en 2021?

Gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Esta es una buena pregunta, pero podria llegar a dar a alguna discusion. Que una libreria sea vieja (o te parezca vieja), no quiere decir que no se siga usando... cuidado con eso.. php tiene esos metodos, y hay varias preguntas al respecto en el sitio...

Comment: En PHP se suele usar `password_hash`  para guardar la contraseña encriptada y `password_verify` para verificarla. En 2021 es seguro, es una función de PHP, está actualizada y solamente debes cuidar de observar ciertas prácticas recomendadas. Te recomiendo que empieces leyendo la documentación propia de PHP si no lo has hecho y si tienes dudas concretas entonces puedes preguntar aquí, exponiendo dicha duda.

Comment: El problema con las contraseñas no está del lado del servidor, si no del usuario. Muchos hashes de contraseñas ya forman parte de diccionarios con millones de posibles combinaciones (incluyendo cambiar letras por números, palabras de algún idioma + números, etc), así que no importa el algoritmo que uses, tienes que impedir que el usuario pueda guardar contraseñas sencillas y predecibles en la BD. Por tu parte puedes usar técnicas como [salt](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.crypt.php) para agregar una capa de complejidad adicional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa password_hash para guardar la contraseña encriptada
Usa password_verify para verificar su es o no correcta, true.